# Migrating to Firebase/Crashlytics from Firebafirebase Crash Reporting OLD

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I tried to migrate from firebase/crash reporting to firebase/crashlytics and it just hangs there on this screen.

[image]

I followed the directions with one difference when it told me to add the following line

"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"

I got an error that said I was missing the app key / api key, which I gave to it. An odd wrinkle I noticed, was that the app had still had a Crashlytics account from before. We originally had Fabric.io/Crashlytics then moved to Firebase/Crash Reporting, now we're moving to Firebase/Crashlytics. Anyways when I go to that account. It actually detects my crashes.

I'm not sure what to do. I may try nuking the app from Fabric.io/Crashlytics tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete the fabric keys in the info.plist. After that occurred

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"
```

Worked without a api key and build secret.